# Strange date when using dateformatter transfer a nsstring to nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate

Then code is below:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-4-23 10:08"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

and the log is :
2015-05-17 23:24:58.244 test[25628:871758] 2015-04-23 02:08:00 +0000

why the nssting is 10:08,the date is 02:08?
Thank you.

Comment: You live in the UTC+8 timezone, don't you? What you are seeing if correct. The log shows the time in the UTC timezone.

Comment: Yes, it can automatically change the timezone when nsdate transfers to nssting or nsstring transfer to nsdate?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Nothing is wrong with your code. It's simply how the date is logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSDate description is always logging the date using +000 timezone. You need to use the date format to get the correct formatted date.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-04-23 10:08"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: What's the point of this? This simply logs the same thing as the original string.